# MySQL EXPLAIN EXTENDED filtered column (obviously it's not a percentage)

Tags: mysql, explain

I've been searching for this and they all state some sort of percentage, explain this:

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT * FROM PageAccess ORDER BY AccessId DESC LIMIT 20;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PageAccess;
```

Giving:

```
id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, filtered, Extra
1, 'SIMPLE', 'PageAccess', 'index', '', 'PRIMARY', '4', '', 20, 9295.00, ''
```

(Yes, filtered = 9295.00)

and:

```
1830
```

For count(*)

Yes I want the last 20 rows, AccessId is the auto-incremented primary key.

What does 9295 mean!?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Source http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain-output.html#explain_filtered

> The filtered column indicates an estimated percentage of table rows
>   that will be filtered by the table condition. That is, rows shows the
>   estimated number of rows examined and rows × filtered / 100 shows the
>   number of rows that will be joined with previous tables. This column
>   is displayed if you use [EXPLAIN EXTENDED](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain-extended.html).

In the filtered 100% means that all rows from this table are filtered.
So getting higher value is not worrisome since its a good sign, means it
does not have to read as much data from the table.

This is how its calculated. Say I have a table called `users` Lets run some analysis on it.

```
mysql> select count(*) from users ;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|    79309 |
+----------+
```

You can see there are 79309 rows in the table. Now lets run explain

```
mysql> explain extended select * from users order by idusers desc limit 20 ;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered  | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |   20 | 396545.00 |       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-----------+-------+
```

Now wondering why `filtered = 396545.00`

Well the calculation is simple.

**The table has total rows = 79309 say its tx.**

**The explain shows rows = 20 say its tx1.**

**The filtered is calculated as**

```
(tx / tx1)*100 = 396545.00
```

So if this value is high means the query is good and not reading everything from the table.

So not to confuse this is not the number of rows that the query will look its a relative calculation of % over number of rows available to the number of rows fetched.

If it becomes 100 meaning the query is looking all the available rows in the table.

Comment: So 20% means ... 80% means... (to show contrast) what if it is *ahem* OVER 9000!

Comment: @AlecTeal you did not get how its calculated. Check my updated answer !!

Comment: So what would filtered=78 mean? (Also, I am guessing rows is the number it actually looked at, not what the query returns. Then 78% means of those it looked at 78% were useful - so high values mean it got A LOT of use out of data?)

Comment: The docs say "rows × filtered / 100 shows the number of rows that will be joined with previous table"... so wouldn't a lower `filtered` number mean less rows are joined resulting in a faster query?

Comment: @billynoah don't get confused by this, its really an approximation or in other words its a ratio, so basically it's ratio of records to be returned from the fetched. Hence the calculation. It may be changed in future version of mysql to provide a better idea, however the explain has some limitations and sometimes it could be misleading. In real world it would be fairly difficult to predict how optimizer will deal with the query just by seeing the `explain`. But the idea was to provide significant hint about the query being executed and if necessary do better optimization.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty - Is higher or lower better?  I'm saying that joining less rows would result in a faster query, but your answer and response both indicate otherwise.  Still confused

Comment: @billynoah more than 100% is considered to be better. Since with the ratio calculation shows it, I would suggest you to have a table with about a million rows and then check explain extended and then do the manual calculation as its shown in answer you will get the answer.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty - I've been running explain extended for years and I've never seen anything higher than 100.  Only lower.  Since it's a percentage which indicates the amount of rows needed for the join it can't be higher than 100%.  Is the example you gave above *actual* explain output from a query?  If so, what version of MySQL are you using because it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I agree with @billynoah that the filtered value cannot go more than 100% but can be lower. I really doubt that it is the correct explain.